How do I add a general progress bar for the entire copying process (all files), leaving the progress bar for each of the files untouched?
friends! How do I add a general progress bar for the entire copying process (all files), leaving the progress bar for each of the files and the multithreaded copying process intact?
def copy_file(src_file, dst_file, pbar):
    src_mtime = os.path.getmtime(src_file)
    with open(src_file, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst_file, 'wb') as fdst:
        copied_size = 0
        block_size = 2 * 1024 * 1024
        while True:
            buf = fsrc.read(block_size)
            if not buf:
                break
            fdst.write(buf) 
            pbar.update(len(buf))
            copied_size += len(buf)
    os.utime(dst_file, (src_mtime, src_mtime))

def copy_with_progress(src, dst, media_type, date_format):
    local_timezone = get_local_timezone()
    if local_timezone is None:
        local_timezone = timezone.utc
    
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
            for file in files:
                if not file.endswith('.XML'):
                    src_file = os.path.join(root, file)
                    src_mtime = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(src_file), tz=timezone.utc).astimezone(local_timezone)
                    dst_folder = os.path.join(dst, media_type, src_mtime.strftime(date_format))
                    os.makedirs(dst_folder, exist_ok=True)
                    dst_file = os.path.join(dst_folder, file)
                    if os.path.exists(dst_file):
                        if src_file == dst_file:
                            pbar = tqdm(total=os.path.getsize(src_file), unit='B', unit_scale=True, desc=os.path.basename(src_file))
                            futures.append(executor.submit(copy_file, src_file, dst_file, pbar))
                        else:
                            dst_mtime = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(dst_file), tz=timezone.utc).astimezone(local_timezone)
                            src_size = os.path.getsize(src_file)
                            dst_size = os.path.getsize(dst_file)
                            if src_size == dst_size:
                                if src_mtime == dst_mtime:
                                    continue
                                else:
                                    count = 1
                                    while True:
                                        prefixed_file = f"{count}_{file}"
                                        prefixed_dst_file = os.path.join(dst_folder, prefixed_file)
                                        if os.path.exists(prefixed_dst_file):
                                            prefixed_mtime = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(prefixed_dst_file), tz=timezone.utc).astimezone(local_timezone)
                                            if src_mtime == prefixed_mtime:
                                                break
                                            else:
                                                count += 1
                                        else:
                                            pbar = tqdm(total=os.path.getsize(src_file), unit='B', unit_scale=True, desc=os.path.basename(src_file))
                                            futures.append(executor.submit(copy_file, src_file, prefixed_dst_file, pbar))
                                            break
                            else:
                                count = 1
                                while True:
                                    prefixed_file = f"{count}_{file}"
                                    prefixed_dst_file = os.path.join(dst_folder, prefixed_file)
                                    if os.path.exists(prefixed_dst_file):
                                        prefixed_mtime = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(prefixed_dst_file), tz=timezone.utc).astimezone(local_timezone)
                                        if src_mtime == prefixed_mtime:
                                            break
                                        else:
                                            count += 1
                                    else:
                                        pbar = tqdm(total=os.path.getsize(src_file), unit='B', unit_scale=True, desc=os.path.basename(src_file))
                                        futures.append(executor.submit(copy_file, src_file, prefixed_dst_file, pbar))
                                        break
                    else:
                        pbar = tqdm(total=os.path.getsize(src_file), unit='B', unit_scale=True, desc=os.path.basename(src_file))
                        futures.append(executor.submit(copy_file, src_file, dst_file, pbar))

        for future in futures:
            future.result()

I tried to implement a general progress bar, but it only worked if I sacrificed multithreading, or I would be without separate progress bars for each of the files.
